# How to access templatized static variable of a class in multiple places in c++

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, c++14, c++17

I am working on a functional simulator project in c++. My aim is to store last 50 debug log statements in  a rolling buffer and display them whenever there is a error in the simulator. This will help be debug faster. Else I will have to note down the cycle when there is a error and re-run the simulator with logs enabled which is time consuming and slow.

In file abc.h Loging structure stores debug log statements, simulation cycle at which the log was generated etc

```
template <typename T, typename... U>
struct Logging {
    ......
}
```

The following templatized class in abc.h holds a static member which is the rolling window holding last 50 log debug statements

```
template <typename T> 
class LogGlobal {
   public:    
       static std::deque<T> last_50_logs; //rolling window of last 50 log statements

};
template <typename T> std::deque<T> LogGlobal<T>::last_50_logs = {};
```

Inside debug_log function in abc.h I push some objects to the static variable like shown below:

```
template <typename T, typename... U>
void debug_log(T&& t, U&&... u) const
{
    //other code to ensure that this deque holds last 50 log statements only is not written here for simplicity
    LogGlobal<Logging<T, U...>>::last_50_logs.push_back(<Logging<T, U...>{...}); 
}
```

Inside abc.cpp file, we have a error handing function which is called whenever there is a error in the simulator.

```
void error_handler()
{
    //I want to access the last_50_logs static variable here but I don't have information about the template T and U here. How do I solve this?
}
```

In the error_handler function I do not have access to what is the type of the template that is used to create LogGlobal class. Is there a way or workaround to know these details?

**One way to solve this problem is whenever I push to last_50_logs, I can store log statements as std::string instead of template T and U inside Logging structure. But this is really really slow as string operations are expensive.**

Comment: There are many  `static std::deque<T> last_50_logs;` as one will exists for every `LogGlobal` class instantiated with a different `T`.

Comment: @RichardCritten so the only solution is stringify the template T and U and add them to Logging structure?

Comment: Every LogGlobal<whatever> has its own variable because they are separate classes! If you want there to only be one last_50_logs variable then don't put it inside a template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> One way to solve this problem is whenever I push to last_50_logs, I can store log statements as std::string instead of template T and U inside Logging structure. But this is really really slow as string operations are expensive.

Well, you can't store the log events as some unknown type `T`, because ... then you don't know what the type is.

However, you can use some kind of type erasure to defer formatting until (unless) you actually need the string. For example, you can store a `std::function<std::string()>` object in your deque,

```
using DeferredLog = std::function<std::string()>;
class LogGlobal {
   public:    
       static std::deque<DeferredLog> last_50_logs; //rolling window of last 50 log statements
};

template <typename T, typename... U>
void debug_log(T&& t, U&&... u) const
{
    // blah blah blah circular buffer
    LogGlobal<Logging<T, U...>>::last_50_logs.push_back(
      [t, u...] () { return format_log(t, u...); }
    ); 
}
```

Note that the type erasure does have some overhead, and all the arguments need to be captured by value, so it's not guaranteed to be faster than just formatting a fixed-width string. Benchmark it and see. You can always hand-roll something less general than a `std::function` with a lambda capture if it seems worthwhile.

Comment: Thanks, this works. I didn't benchmark it, I am happy with the overall runtime of my simulation. It is much much better than when I store the logs as std::string objects

Answer (score 0):

A different type for each log message, like in your example, is too cumbersome and inconvenient to be practical.

Logs are often text, so that a natural solution is to use a circular buffer of `std::string` for your log messages. You format the message into a `std::string` and store that into the buffer.

For structured logging there must be another specific (base) class for your log records.

---

If you'd rather not format messages until they are output, have a ring buffer of format functions which copy the log message arguments.

Each format function is a lambda closure object with log message arguments captured by value. By value is to prevent references from becoming dangling, at least. You can still pass a pointer which may later become dangling, but it is possible to reject pointer arguments (unless they point to compile-time constants, with non-standard compiler extensions.) at compile time.

A complete example:

```
#include <boost/circular_buffer.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

struct LogHistory {
    using FormatFn = std::function<void(std::ostream&)>;
    boost::circular_buffer<FormatFn> last_10_logs_{10};

    template<class... T>
    void log(T&&... args) {
        last_10_logs_.push_back([=](std::ostream& s) { (s << ... << args); });
    }
};

int main() {
    LogHistory l;
    for(int i = 0; i < 20; ++i)
        l.log("hello ", i);

    for(auto const& f : l.last_10_logs_) {
        f(std::cout);
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
}
```

Outputs:

```
hello 10
hello 11
hello 12
hello 13
hello 14
hello 15
hello 16
hello 17
hello 18
hello 19
```

Answer (score 0):

Sooner or later you'd still have to stringify this data if you want to show it to user (most of loggers work this way). But if there is some need to always keep it as binary data (lets say you gather data which is later dumped to file and can be decoded on demand) then you can look into `std::any`, it stores typedata in runtime, but such modification would require bigger changes in your code.

Comment: I can stringify only the last 50 log statements when there is a error which is not slow.

Comment: You could log to a `deque<pair<any, function<string(any)>>>` that has the data and a stringifying lambda.